# vhdl code understanding, if there is modelsim error about possible infinite loop

Tags: vhdl

```
--
-- VHDL Architecture di_lib.ShiftRegister1.ShiftRegister1
--
-- Created:
--          by - 294162.UNKNOWN (VD1210)
--          at - 14:19:36 10-04-2015
--
-- using Mentor Graphics HDL Designer(TM) 2010.2a (Build 7)
--
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

LIBRARY WORK;
USE WORK.CALC_PKG.ALL;
LIBRARY di_lib;
USE di_lib.calc_pkg.all;
USE ieee.NUMERIC_STD.all;

ENTITY ShiftRegister1 IS
   PORT( 
      d_out       : OUT    Std_Logic_Vector (7 DOWNTO 0);
      multiplexer : IN     Std_Logic_Vector (7 DOWNTO 0);
      carry       : IN     std_logic;
      load_out    : IN     std_logic;
      f_code      : IN     std_logic_vector (2 DOWNTO 0);
      out_loaded  : OUT    std_logic
   );

-- Declarations

END ShiftRegister1 ;

--
ARCHITECTURE ShiftRegister1 OF ShiftRegister1 IS
BEGIN

  ShiftRegister1 : process

  variable remember, multiplexer_var       : std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0);
  variable state          : std_logic_vector(2 DOWNTO 0);
  variable counter        : integer := 0; 
        begin

          state := f_code;

        case state is

        when "000" => 
            d_out <= multiplexer;

        when "001" =>
            d_out <= multiplexer;

        when "010" =>
                multiplexer_var := multiplexer;
            if load_out = '1' then 
              if carry = '1' then
                --shifting is done without function SRL
                remember(0) := multiplexer_var(1);
                remember(1) := multiplexer_var(2);
                remember(2) := multiplexer_var(3);
                remember(3) := multiplexer_var(4);
                remember(4) := multiplexer_var(5);
                remember(5) := multiplexer_var(6);
                remember(6) := multiplexer_var(7);
                remember(7) := '1';
                d_out <= remember;
                out_loaded <= '1';

              elsif  carry = '0' then
                remember(0) := multiplexer_var(1);
                remember(1) := multiplexer_var(2);
                remember(2) := multiplexer_var(3);
                remember(3) := multiplexer_var(4);
                remember(4) := multiplexer_var(5);
                remember(5) := multiplexer_var(6);
                remember(6) := multiplexer_var(7);
                remember(7) := '0';
                d_out <= remember;
                out_loaded <= '1';
              end if;
            end if;

        when "011" =>
            if load_out = '1' then
              d_out <= multiplexer;
              out_loaded <= '1';
            end if;

        when others => null;

        end case;
   end process;

END ARCHITECTURE ShiftRegister1;
```

--ERROR GIVEN --

> -- Compiling architecture shiftregister1 of shiftregister1
>   **Warning: [2] <...>vhd(109): (vcom-1090) Possible infinite loop:   Process contains no WAIT statement.
>   Warning: Cannot create unmappedlibrary work

QUESTION:
where possibly in this code an infinite loop can occur?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In VHDL, a process's execution time is instantaneous. Also, a process is re-executed as soon as it finishes. Thus your process forms an infinite loop.

To fix this, whether add a `wait` statement, or use sensitivity list. A process with a sensitivity list will only execute when one of sensitivity list signals changes. Something like:

```
process(load_out, carry, multiplexer, f_code)
```

You have to make sure to add all signals that the process uses on the sensitivity list, otherwise you will get a simulation mismatch, as sensitivity list is ignored for synthesis.

Comment: @Tomas: If this answers you question, then please accept the answer by clicking the check mark, as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).  See more in [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).